# Liskov Substitution Principle: Confusion about additional Functionalities of sub types

Tags: flutter, dart, software-design, solid-principles, solid

I'm working on a social app using flutter, so there are posts to get published. Suppose there are two types of posts.

- `Post` contains only text.
- `ImagePost` contains images and text.

The following code is an example to demonstrate the problem.

```
class Post{
  
  String text;
  Post(this.text);
}

class ImagePost extends Post{

  String image;
  ImagePost(this.image, super.text);
}

void printy(Post p){ // p can be a Post or ImagePost
  
  print(p.text);

// for now, it's conformation to LSP

  if(p.runtimeType == ImagePost){
  print(p.image ); // error: cause Post (p) doesn't contain image field
}
}

void main() {
  Post post = Post('hi there');
  ImagePost imagePost = ImagePost('dumy link' , 'welcome');
  printy(imagePost);
}
```

The above code should conform to the Liskov Substitution Principle: *Subtypes must be substitutable for their base types*; but there's an additional attribute `image` inside `ImagePost` which I need to access inside the method `printy`. I can't because the `Post p` parameter doesn't contain an image.

I could bypass that problem by defining a `printy` method in the base class and overriding it in subclasses; but there's no `printy` method in the real project. It has a separate `postBuilder` that needs to access the `image` to render it on the screen, if the post is an `ImagePost`.

In short: how can I access the `image` property inside a separate `printy` client, when the post is an `ImagePost`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `is` to check for object type. The object tested will become the second operand (the type) inside the `if` scope.

```
if (p is ImagePost) {
  // p is now an ImagePost in this scope
  print(p.image); // You can access the `image` property
}
```

---

See also:

- [Type test operators](https://dart.dev/language/operators#type-test-operators)
- ['Effective Dart: Usage' - discourage use of .runtimeType](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/3354)

Comment: thank you, for the example in the question the dart analyzer has treated the  post as an ImagePost after using is operator, but as you know printy method is a postBuilder means: Tree of widgets in flutter: eg  if (post is ImagePost) Image.network(post.imageLink, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,) else SizedBox.shrink(), i have used is operator but still doesn't treat post as an ImagePost, but your idea is working the problem still in the nature of the client

Comment: Make a local copy before doing the type cast. Do the check on the copied variable, and use that copied variable

Comment: thank you Dhaf appreciate your response, i try.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow `polymorphism` and method `overriding`. Instead of directly accessing the image property in the printy method, you can create a method in the base class `Post` and override it in the `ImagePost` subclass.

```
class Post {
  String text;

  Post(this.text);

  
  void printContent() {
    print(text);
  }
}

class ImagePost extends Post {
  String image;

  ImagePost(this.image, String text) : super(text);

  
  @override
  void printContent() {
    super.printContent(); 
    print(image); 
  }
}

void printy(Post p) {
  p.printContent();
}

void main() {
  Post post = Post('Aizan Sagheer');
  ImagePost imagePost = ImagePost('Any image link', 'Text');
  printy(post);
  printy(imagePost);
}
```

By this, you are following the LSP by providing a substitutable behavior for the base type.

Comment: thank you, i have already made that temporarily, mentioned in the question. but this violates the SRP because each one doesn't supposed to have a printy method eg: postBuilder